# Is there any need for me to use wstring in the following case

Tags: c++, unicode, mfc

Currently, I am developing an app for a China customer. China customer are mostly switch to GB2312 language in their OS encoding. I need to write a text file, which will be encoded using GB2312.

1. I use *std::ofstream file*
2. I compile my application under MBCS mode, not unicode.
3. I use the following code, to convert *CString* to *std::string*, and write it to file using ofstream

---

```
std::string Utils::ToString(CString& cString) {
    /* Will not work correctly, if we are compiled under unicode mode. */
    return (LPCTSTR)cString;
}
```

To my surprise. It just works. I thought I need to at least make use of wstring. I try to do some investigation.

Here is the MBCS.txt generated.

[alt text http://sites.google.com/site/yanchengcheok/Home/stackoverflow0.PNG](http://sites.google.com/site/yanchengcheok/Home/stackoverflow0.PNG)

1. I try to print a single character named 脚 (its value is 0xBDC5)
2. When I use CString to carry this character, its length is 2.
3. When I use Utils::ToString to perform conversion to std::string, the returned string length is 2.
4. I write to file using std::ofstream

My question is :

1. When I exam MBCS.txt using a hex editor, the value is displayed as BD (LSB) and C5 (MSB). But I am using little endian machine. Isn't hex editor should show me C5 (LSB) and BD (MSB)? I check from wikipedia. GB2312 seems doesn't specific endianness.
2. It seems that using std::string + CString just work fine for my case. May I know in what case, the above methodology will not work? and when I should start to use wstring?

Comment: You dont need to use wstring until/unless you decide to get rid of gb2312 encoding and go with the universal encoding unicode offers. in which case, utf16 can be stored in BE or LE formats, but has a byte-order marker that can be prefixed onto a document (notepad will save unicode documents with a BOM) where the reading of the BOM can be used to indicate the endianness of the document.

Comment: @Chris, wstring isn't tied to unicode.  I know there are locales used on Solaris for which wchar_t doesn't store the unicode codet.

Comment: true, but in the context of GB2312, wstring would be the "use unicode" option.

Comment: @Chris, could you explain why? I see no fundamental reason for a locale using GB2312 as encoding to embed conversion table to and from Unicode when you can use something which has an algorithmic correspondence with the code structure (characters are designed by pairs of numbers in the 33-126 range).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About 1.  Endianness is a problem you meet when you serialize a unit in term of smaller units (i.e. serialize seizets in term of octets).  I'm far from being a specialist of CJK encodings, but it seems to me that GB2112 is a coded character set which can be used with several encoding schemes.  The encoding schemes cited in the wikipedia page as being used for GB2112 (ISO 2022, EUC-CN and HZ) are all defined in terms of octets.  So there is no endianness issue if serialized as octets.

Contrast this with Unicode encoding schemes: UTF-8 is defined in terms of octets and has no endianness issue when serialized as octets, UTF-16 is defined in terms of seizets and if serialized as octets endianness must be specified, UTF-32 is defined in terms of 32 bits units and if serialized as octets endianness must be specified.